# Handlebars not supporting render when adding assemble to a yeoman webapp project

Tags: web-applications, gruntjs, yeoman, assemble

I created a webapp using yeoman and the default webapp generator. Now I am trying to add assemble.io to the project using these instructions: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/assemble.md

When I execute grunt serve or build the follwoing error message apears:

```
Running "assemble:pages" (assemble) task
handlebars does not support render.
Assembling .tmp/blog.html ERROR
Warning: handlebars does not support render. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried to fix this error by installing handlebars, handlebars-helpers and assemble-handlebars but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One common cause of this error is that **node_modules/assemble-handlebars** doesn't contain a node_modules folder.

I'm not sure why, but sometimes node doesn't recursively install the modules for that folder.

A short term fix is to navigate to **node_modules/assemble-handlebars** in your terminal then run **npm install**.

`cd node_modules/assemble-handlebars`

`npm install`

Grunt should now run the assemble tasks without any error.

Answer (score 0):

yo-webapp doesn't add a version to the package.json.

In grunt-assemble, we're using assemble-handlebars by default, which uses handlebars-helpers.In the version of handlebars-helpers that's being used, we're using to for YAML formatting, which is using handy and trying to get the package.json version.

Since grunt-assemble attempts to first load assemble-handlebars then falls back to handlebars if it fails to load, handlebars is trying to be used as the engine directly, which doesn't have a .render method.

**Solution is:**

> It works if you add a version property to your package.json file.

In later newer versions of assemble and handlebars-helpers we're doing things differently so this type of error won't happen.